# Where can I get/buy a repair manual for a Mercedes-Benz CLK200 Kompressor -2002?

Tags: maintenance, mercedes-benz

I have checked [haynes.com](http://haynes.com) but it seems like they only cover C230 - C350. Any other good sources to check? I have tried to contact Mercedes-Benz Europe directly via e-mail for a regular manual, but they haven't answered that now in 4 weeks, so a question on repair manual seems to be in vain.

Comment: I would suggest phoning your nearest Mercedes dealer, rather than using email.

Comment: It appears that isn't a Bentley Manual that covers your car either, I am not sure how much your model shares with the C230 but that might be best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Mercedes Benz repair manuals are very well kept by the company. Haynes or any other repair manual providers usually don't touch upon these vehicle. The reason is due to the complexity of the the vehicles systems.

- **Most** issues have to be diagnosed using `Star Diagnostics` (factory scan tool), and
- Documentation for disassembly & reassembly procedures, technical bulletins, and, recalls, is found in their `WIS` system (log in required factory software).
- Component locations and wiring diagrams are found on `Star Finder` database (log in required web-site)

Also, replacing any modules require the `Star Diagnostics` computer in order to transfer the coding from the old component to the new one. Anything on the `Engine CAN` communication system can only be ordered by a dealership and only after the owner of the vehicle provides proof of ownership (license, registration, and title) as well as a written signature.

Mercedes Benz puts a lot of work into developing their vehicles. They don't want *anyone* except trained mechanics working on them.